# Why does this cell not work even though I entered the correct identifier?

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

1- tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TestTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

2- tableView.register(TestTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

**When the cellForRowAt function runs, this function returns UITAbleViewCell(). Why ?**

**[image]**

[image]

**Why does this function return UITableViewCell() ?**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    switch items[indexPath.row] {
      
    case .favCountries(let countries):
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? TestTableViewCell {
        cell.configureCountryFav(with: countries)
        return cell
      }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
  }
```

Cell:

```
class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
  
  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does the `if let` line get executed?  If yes, what does `dequeueReusableCell` actually return?

Comment: The if let line doesn't work sir.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't really information that lets anyone help you.  If you would like to answer the questions I asked, I'll see if there's anything I can solve.

Comment: Could you share cell registration function too? What do you mean by numbers 1 and 2? Maybe cell is not registering in the correct lifecycle.
Second thought, does `switch` execute? what if `items` are empty

Comment: is it missing cases? Let's start at the beginning, have you checked to see if you are sending .favCountries correctly? and you have cell.configureCountryFav(with: countries) but in your uitableViewCell i don't see that function.

Comment: ```switch``` is not empty sir. 
```case .favCountries(let countries):
print("test: \(countries)") // isworking
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countryComponentCell") as? CountryComponentCell {
        cell.configure(with: countries)
//        cell.didTappedFavButton = presenter?.didRemovedFavList(code:)
        return cell
      }```